# Proper way to change Model ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I've made some changes using the [question I'd answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293995/increase-activemodel-id-range-to-8-byte/). I need to have 8 bytes on the Model `id`.

I need to change the `id` to a different unique number:

```
Product.where(title: "Foo").update_attributes(id: 123456789)
# NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
```

I've tried [few answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301635/how-to-change-primary-id-of-a-record-in-rails) but still getting errors. Do you need to see each error based on which method used? I know this is caused by the 8 byte changes I've done. Have I done it the correct way? How to change the `id`?

**Edit**

For some strange and scary reason, I have to recreate the database for this to work:

```
Product.where(title: "Foo").update_all(id: 123456789)
```

Comment: Why do you need to change the `id` just because you've switched its type to `bigint`?

Comment: A product is pulled from x then save in my db, they that same product goes to y and save. I need y's id to match in local db so I update last save product with y's id.

Comment: that makes no sense, the id is an auto-incrementing column so the value is created set by the db when you insert a row. You don't really ever change PK columns.

Comment: @max Correct but I need the `:limit` to be `8`. Also, I must be able to change to another unique number. Any other way?

Comment: I think you'd be better off keeping your own `id`s separate from the external ones. So instead of trying to sync up your `id`s with theirs you'd have a separate `external_id` column that contained theirs.

Comment: @muistooshort Then that means I could no longer use relations. `Product.where(id: 1111).variants`. Then again I could, `Product.where(external_id: 1111).variants.where(external_id: 1111)`

Comment: Why not? You'd link your tables together using your `id`s and only have to worry about their `id`s at the edges.

Comment: An example to test, please?

Comment: is that an associated object? if not, you can just re-create it with a new id and delete the old object