# Seeds file - adding id column to existing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My seeds file populated the countries table with a list of countries.  But now it needs to be changed to hard-code the id (instead of rails generating the id column for me).

I added the id column and values as per below:

```
 zmb: {id: 103,code: 'ZMB', name: Country.human_attribute_name(:zambia, default: 'Error!'), display_order: nil, create_user: user, update_user: user, eff_date: Time.now, exp_date: default_exp_date},
    skn: {id: 104,code: 'SKN', name: Country.human_attribute_name(:st_kitts_and_nevis, default: 'Error!'), display_order: nil, create_user: user, update_user: user, eff_date: Time.now, exp_date: default_exp_date}

countries.each { |key, value| countries_for_later[key] = Country.find_or_initialize_by(id: value[:id]); countries_for_later[key].assign_attributes(value); countries_for_later[key].save!; }
```

Above it just a snippet.  I have added an id: for every country.

But when I run `db:seed` I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Code has already been taken
```

I am new to rails so I'm not sure what is causing this - is it because the ID column already exists in the database?

Comment: Do you have validation on any of your models for code? It would seem you have validates uniqueness of code on one of your models. Probably country ... if you want to get to the errors for objects you can just use `puts country.errors.inspect`

Comment: validates_uniqueness_of :code is in place but I can't find any duplicated

Comment: I would check your seed file again. Note that when you run your seed file you might have data in your db already which would cause the validation to fire.

Comment: Yeah the db is fully populated but I should be able to run db:seed as many time as I want without error?  Should it not just ignore anything thats already there?  Does the db have to be empty to run a seed?

Comment: No. If you want to do that you would need to use `find_or_create_by`. For example - `Country.find_or_create_by(code: 'ABC', name: 'Country ABC')`. That will make your seed file rerunnable. Right now it sounds like you are just using new and save or create. This will definitely cause the validation to fire.

Comment: I am using Country.find_or_initialize_by  - is that ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75789/discussion-between-ryan-neal-mes-and-user3437721).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think is happening is you have existing data in your database ... let's say

```
[{id:1 , code: 'ABC'},
{id:2 , code: 'DEF'}]
```

Now you run your seed file which has `{id: 3, 'DEF'}` for example.

Because you are using `find_or_initialize_by` with id you are running into errors. Since you can potentially insert duplicates.

I recon you should just clear your data, but you can try doing `find_or_initialize_by` using `code` instead of `id`. That way you wont ever have a problem of trying to create a duplicate country code.

`Country.find_or_initialize_by(code: value[:code])`

I think you might run into problems with your ids, but you will have to test that. It's generally bad practice to do what you are doing. Whether they ids change or now should be irrelevant. Your seed file should reference the objects that are being created not ids.

Also make sure you aren't using any default_scopes ... this would affect how `find_or_initialize_by` works.

Comment: I had a default_scope in the model which was causing this error. Looks like I need to move this scope into the controller

Comment: Create a new scope in your model and use that scope in your controller and it should work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The error is about Code: `Code has already been taken`.  You've a validation which says Code should be uniq. You can delete all Countries and load seeds again.

Comment: its saying that one of the country codes is not unique?  But this error didnt happen before I added IDs?

Comment: I have checked the country codes and they are all unique?

Comment: I ran a rake db:reset and that went ok, but running a db:seed after this failed with the same error message

Comment: rake db:reset load seeds too. when you run rake db:seed you try duplicate data. then validations fail.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in the rails console:

```
Country.delete_all
```

Then re-run the seed:

```
rake db:seed
```

Comment: Are you in the rails console? So typing 'rails console' from within your rails directory?

Comment: still got the same error after doing this... do you need to commit?

Comment: I ran a rake db:reset and that went ok, but running a db:seed after this failed with the same error message

Comment: OK then I think two rows in your seed must have the same code. Can you check this? Or is there too many rows?

Comment: there is over 100 rows, I copied into Excel and tried to find duplicates but there were none

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is due to duplicate entry. In that case run `ModelName.delete_all` in your rails console and then run `rake db:seed` again being in the current project directory. Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line for

```
countries_for_later[key].id = value[:id]
```

the problem is that you can't set :id => value[:id] to Country.new because id is a special attribute, and is automatically protected from mass-assignment

so it will be:

```
countries.each { |key, value| 
  countries_for_later[key] = Country.find_or_initialize_by(id: value[:id])
  countries_for_later[key].assign_attributes(value)
  countries_for_later[key].id = value[:id] if countries_for_later[key].new_record?
  countries_for_later[key].save(false)
}
```

Comment: still get :  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Code has already been taken

Comment: try with save(false) to stop validation, i believe you have a validation for code uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Code has already been taken
```

is the default error message for the uniqueness validator for :code.

Running rake db:reset will definitely clear and reseed your database. Not sure about the hardcoded ids though.

Check this : [Overriding id on create in ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431617/overriding-id-on-create-in-activerecord)

you will have to disable protection with

```
save(false)
```

or

```
Country.create(attributes_for_country, without_protection: true)
```

I haven't tested this though, be careful with your validators.

Answer (score 0):

The ids data that you are using in your seeds file: does that have any meaning outside of Rails?  Eg

```
zmb: {id: 103,code: 'ZMB',
```

is this some external data for Zambia, where 103 is it's ID in some internationally recognised table of country codes?  (in my countries database, Zambia's "numcode" value is 894).  If it is, then you should rename it to something else, and let Rails decide what the id field should be.

Generally, mucking about with the value of ID in rails is going to be a pain in the ass for you.  I'd recommend not doing it.  If you need to do tests on data, then use some other unique field (like 'code') to test whether associations etc have been set up, or whatever you want to do, and let Rails worry about what value to use for ID.

Comment: No its just the default id and has no specific meaning.  I just want to keep the ids the same

Comment: I'd really recommend not doing that.  You will end up spending a lot of time mucking about, since you are going to be fighting rails all the way.  It's a risky testing strategy anyway:  you could test that a record has a given ID but it could be the wrong "proper" data with a different ID to what you expect.  Always better to test the proper data (in this case i'd recommend using the `code` field as the basis for any tests which check which record was returned or whatever).

Comment: The id from the country table is used in another table. So I don't want the country ids to ever change as that would impact the other table.   So thought hardcoding them was best,  in case someone deleted one from the seeds file..