# Rails / Active Record 5.0.0 set id manually before create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm connecting a Rails application to another database and can't change the schema.  This other database has a `NOT NULL` constraint on the id field for all of its tables (using uuid for id's).

I'm trying to assign an `id` manually in a `before_create` but it seems the attribute is protected.

Any way around this?

Rails 5.0.0

Comment: maybe one of these answers help -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431617/overriding-id-on-create-in-activerecord

Comment: @neongrau I know I was able to manually set an id that way in <= 4.0, however in 5 it seems something has changed and this no longer works.

Comment: Is that a MSSQL database you are using?

Comment: @neongrau It is postgres.  It is actually a database created / used by a Django application.  It seems he Django application assigns an id before save (uuid), whereas rails does not.

Answer (score 0):

Add a uid field to the new database and use `find_by(uid: uid)`

Comment: I can't change the schema of the other database.