# missing required keys: [:id] rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am using the method for linking to the project. Below the code is there

```
project = Project.new
project.id = value["id"]
project.name = value["project_name"]  
<td width="20%"  class="left"><%= link_to_project(project) %></td>
```

**ERROR**

```
 No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"projects", :id=>#<Project id: 2343, name: " TESTING", description: nil, homepage: "", is_public: false, parent_id: nil, created_on: nil, updated_on: nil, identifier: nil, status: 1, lft: nil, rgt: nil, inherit_members: false, product_backlog_id: nil, default_version_id: nil>} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I got this error its not working. I dont know how to solve this. But rails 3.2 its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This would work in Rails . But no longer works as of `activerecord 3.2.11`which is what Rails 4 depend on. If you like to know more go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431617/overriding-id-on-create-in-activerecord/32490463#32490463) discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i finally i got the solution for that

We have to pass id as parameter like this

```
link_to_project(project,{:id=>project.id})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
link_to(project.name, project)
```

or, more explicitly, this:

```
link_to(project.name, project_path(project))
```

There is more info about this in [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-purpose-of-the-rails-router).