# Reinserted deleted record in rails using the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a record which I deleted and now I need to reinsert it with the same `id` as before. I have the whole object saved. Is there a way I can directly insert this back in the db using the console?

Note: I'm on Rails 4

So I understood how to add it, there is one issue I was using devise and now I don't have the whole `encrypted password` hash. Is there a way around that? Because it is a user account

Comment: A lot of suggestions in below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431617/overriding-id-on-create-in-activerecord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you know the password, you could do:

```
User.new(password: 'user_password').encrypted_password
```

and insert that value in the db.